# Added passport authentication to an existing project and now get a Cannot read property of undefined error

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, knex.js

I have a simple node/express/knex app that can read and edit a postgres db.  I added passport authentication with auth0 and everything works beautifully.  I was about to call it a day when I noticed I can't actually submit changes anymore.  All the pages work that read from the database, but when I go to make a change and call a router.post route, I get an error like this.  The weird thing is absolutely nothing has changed in that section of code.  Happens in three separate routes.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'amp30' of undefined
   at /app/kml/index.js:431:22
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at /app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at Function.handle (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
   at router (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at trim_prefix (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
   at /app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/app/kml/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (/app/kml/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:325:9)
```

Here is the entire route as an example.

```
router.post('/app/post/hydrant', function(req, res) {

  // Update hydrants based on data passed as POST to url/app/app-hydrants-single-edit-post
  knex('hydrants')
    .withSchema('snowmaking')
    .update({
      '30a': req.body.amp30,
      '60a': req.body.amp60,
      water: req.body.water,
      air: req.body.air,
      notes: req.body.notes,
      circuit: req.body.circuit,
      edit_by: req.body.edit_by
    })
    .where({
      id: req.body.id
    })
    .then(function(projectNames) {
      res.render('app-hydrants-single-edit-post');
    });
```

Comment: The error says that `req.body` is undefined. Possible reasons could be: you haven't posted any data, you have incorrectly configured body-parser, or who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be because the body parser has not configured properly. To configure the body parser add the following code in your project(app.js)

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
```

Comment: Yes, I managed to forget a period in the body parser config.  Thanks!!